# Jenkins : env: ‘node’: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu, jenkins

I trying to integrate Jenkins(which running in a docker compose) and nodejs,

I have installed the nodejs plugin :
[nodejs plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qA8HD.png) and I create a job :
[jenkins job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggMJI.png)

but when I run the jobs , it gives me this error :

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZyjH.png)

any help please ?

thanks